# UTF-8 encoding will work on all HTML pages but one

Tags: php, html, symfony, utf-8, twig

I'm setting up a web application in french so I encoded it in UTF-8 because of the many accents. However, all of my HTML pages get encoded but one. As the tags suggest, I am also using PHP, Symfony and twig.

Here is my base twig file called base.html.twig:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <meta charset="UTF-8"/>

        <title>
          {% block title %}
            {{titrePage}}
          {% endblock %}
        </title>

        {% block stylesheets %}
          <link href="/css/base.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/litera/bootstrap.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
        {% endblock %}
    </head>

    <body id="body">
        {% block body %}

          {% block javascripts %}
            <!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>-->
            <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src ="public/js/CreationJS.js"></script>
          {% endblock %}

      {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

(Side note, the CreationJS.js file is still empty)

Then, I have for example the start of my index.html.twig file:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Ajout de métier{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class ="row" id="main">
  <div class = "col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 colonnesLaterales">
    <img src="..\..\public\images\arep-frescc.png" width="300" height="82" alt="Logo"/>
  </div>
  <div class = "col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 colonnesCentrales">
    <div class="titre">Création d'un métier</div>
    {{ form_start(metierForm) }}
```

This one is encoded in UTF-8 when I open it in my browser (Firefox)

Finally, the start of the black sheep creationQuestions.html.twig:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Création de question{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class ="row" id="main">
  <div class = "col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 colonnesLaterales">
    <img src="..\..\public\images\arep-frescc.png" width="300" height="82" alt="Logo"/>
  </div>
  <div class = "col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 colonnesCentrales">
    <div class="titre">Création d'une question</div>
    {{ form_start(questionForm) }}
```

This file does not get encoded in UTF-8.

I am fully aware that they are about the same. I checked their respective controllers, and they both render the correct files.

I checked other pages and they all get encoded in UTF-8 as well, so I do not understand why creationQuestions.html.twig does not.

EDIT: I forgot to add that the non-encoded characters become '�'

Comment: which coding environment do you use?

Comment: I am using VisualStudio 2017

Comment: Make sure that all your physicals files are stored as `UTF-8` as well

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Does all this work better when you remove some parts from the "black sheep file"?

Comment: That… that worked! Thank you very much! I would've never guessed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits to DarkBee for giving me the answer: My creationQuestions.html.twig file was not physically encoded in UTF-8. I converted it, and it worked.

It was that simple

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Twig Escape](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/escape.html)

On a single string or even on your block

```
{{ "your téxt"|e }}
```